# notify-send from within a bash script

Tags: bash, shell, notify-send

I'd like to use notify-send from within a bash script that is running in the background to inform the user about the progress of the script.  More specifically this is a script that automagically runs when a USB flash drive is inserted and runs a scan with ClamAV.

Specifically at line 30 and line 66.  So far, I'm not having any luck.  Can someone give me some advice/help?  Thanks.

```
#!/bin/bash
#doOnUSBinsert_0.2.sh
#Author : Totti
# Make it executable by running 'sudo chmod  x doOnUSBinsert_0.2.sh'


if ! [ -f /etc/udev/rules.d/80-doOnUSBinsert.rules ]
then        # rule not added
   cp "$0" /usr/bin/doOnUSBinsert
   chmod u x /usr/bin/doOnUSBinsert

#   echo 'SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ACTION=="add", RUN ="/path/to/script.sh"' | sudo tee     /etc/udev/rules.d/80-clamscan.rules
   echo 'SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ACTION=="add", RUN ="/usr/bin/doOnUSBinsert & "' | tee     /etc/udev/rules.d/80-doOnUSBinsert.rules
   if  [ $? -eq 0 ]
   then
     echo 'Rule Successfully added. See file "/usr/bin/doOnUSBinsert" if you wish to edit the command'
     exit 0
    else
     echo 'ERROR while adding rule'
     exit 1
   fi
fi



lfile="/tmp/doOnUSBinsert.log"     # udev
lfile2="/tmp/clamscanFromUdev.log"   # clamscan
lfile3="/tmp/doOnUSBinsert_mount.log"   # mount

notify-send "USB SCAN ON INSERT" "Currently scanning with ClamAV"

main ()
{
sleep 12  # let the partitions to mount

   #cat /proc/$$/environ | tr '�' 'n' >> /tmp/udevEnvirn.txt
echo "found $ID_SERIAL"   >> "$lfile"
  cat /etc/mtab | grep "^$part_c"   >> "$lfile.3"

if [ "$ID_SERIAL"x = 'x' ]
then
 echo "Exiting on empty ID_SERIAL"   >> "$lfile"
 exit 1
fi

#Eg: ID_SERIAL --> /dev/disk/by-id/usb-sandisk....42343254343543
#i=0
echo 'searching partitions'   >> "$lfile"

for partitionPath in  $( find /dev/disk/by-id/ -name "*$ID_SERIAL*part*" )
do
  echo "current partition = $partitionPath"   >> "$lfile"
 # part[i  ]="$( readlink -f "$partition" )"        # Eg Output: /dev/sdb1     , /dev/sdb2
  part_c="$( readlink -f $partitionPath )"   
  mpoint="$( cat /etc/mtab | grep "^$part_c"  | awk '{print $2}' )"

  echo "partitionPath= $partitionPath, part = $part_c, mountpoint=  $mpoint"  >>     "$lfile"

  echo "Scaning -->  $mpoint"  >> "$lfile.2"
  ############################################
  clamscan -r --bell "$mpoint"/*  >> "$lfile.2"
  #############################################
done
}

notify-send "USB SCAN ON INSERT" "Finished scanning with ClamAV"

main &
echo ______________________________________  >> "$lfile"
exit 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty new to the linux world, but while looking for a solution for a similar project I found [THIS](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Desktop_notifications#Usage_in_programming)

> Tip: An overview on the available icons can be found here. To send
> desktop notification from a background script running as root (replace
> X_user and X_userid with the user and userid running X respectively):
>
> `sudo -u X_user DISPLAY=:0 DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/X_userid/bus notify-send 'Hello world!' 'This is an example notification.'`

Hope this will help others.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you are running the script it may not have access to the display variable. Try running `export DISPLAY=:0.0` prior to the command.

If you are running the script as a different user, ie root, then you may also need to run it as `su - <logged in user> -c notify-send ...` (I usually don't need to do this, but I remember having to at one point - but I cant recall which distro or version I was on at the time.)

Comment: Ok, thanks - it worked on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS with Unity:  export DISPLAY=:0.0
su - $USER -c "/usr/bin/notify-send 'USB SCAN' 'Currently scanning USB with ClamAV'"

Answer (score 0):

After many trials and errors, here's what works for me to notify all connected users, with notify-send, within a bash script executed as root with cron (weekly), on Linux (Fedora 38/GNOME 44):

```
for n in `who | awk '!_[$1]++ {print $1}'`; do sudo -u "$n" DISPLAY=:0 DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/$(sudo -u "$n" id -u)/bus notify-send "Message to users"; done
```

You may note that it can be run with just one command.